# With repository pattern should we define classes for every table in DAL or objects in business layer?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

How to implement repository pattern correctly in c# with entity framework when you have a larger database?

Should we define class for every table implementing Repository interface in DAL (data access layer) or we define objects like this in our business layer?

```
Repository<RetailerMarketplace> retailerMarketplaceRepo = null;
Repository<Marketplace> marketplaceRepo = null;
Repository<Product> productRepo = null;
Repository<OP_FLAGS> opFlagsRepo = null;
Repository<RetailerMarketplaceAttributeMapping> retailerMPAttributesMappingRepo = null;
Repository<EbayVariation> ebayVariationRepo = null;
Repository<ProductIsListed> productIsListedRepo = null;
Repository<Skus_OpFlags> skusOpFlagsRepo = null;
```

Currently i have defined objects like above but i am confused as to what is the correct approach of defining objects and using them either in DAL or business layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create any `Repository` objects in your business layer. You should use a unit of work pattern together with your repository pattern. Your DAL should have a unit of work class that exposes *only the necessary* repositories as properties. This unit of work class acts as the only gateway between your business layer and data access layer.

For example, let's say I have two entities `Foo` and `Bar` structured like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

My `UnitOfWork` class might look like this:

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    private Repository<Foo> foos;

    public Repository<Foo> Foos
    {
        get
        {
            if(foos == null)
                foos = new Repository<Foo>();
            return foos;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

As far as defining a repository for every entity, you need to decide which ones you really need to include. For example my `UnitOfWork` doesn't include a `Repository<Bar>`. Perhaps I did this because I can get to all of the `Bar`s through the linked property on their associated `Foo` and it doesn't make sense in my domain to look up a `Bar` on it's own. Bottom line: it all depends on your domain which repositories you expose. Just choose wisely.

[This article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) was written by the ASP.NET/MVC team but the repository/unit of work principles in it are good practices for anything using Entity Framework. It's a good read whether you are working with MVC or not.

Comment: Thanks alot, it really helped to clear my understanding. All i needed was to implement UnitOfWork pattern in DAL.

Comment: I don't agree with *"Don't create any Repository objects in your business layer."* - repositories are specifically used to control access to the DAL therefore it's perfectly fine to allow them to be created in your BAL (as long as they don't expose any DAL-specific types/functionality). This can be accomplished by having your Repositories return interfaced objects e.g. `Repository<IFoo>`/`Repository<IBar>`.

Comment: @James I didn't suggest making the Repository internal to the DAL; it's still directly exposed through the unit of work. Implementing a unit of work just groups everything together neatly in a single class and that's just one of the pattern's benefits. Why instantiate 5 different repositories in the business layer when you can instantiate a single unit of work that exposes everything you need? This has been suggested as a best practice by lots of Entity Framework experts.

Answer (score 2):

EF has built-in repository objects, they are of type DbSet, which EF initializes on its own. So in your code example they would be like:

```
public DbSet<RetailerMarketplace> RetailerMarketplaces { get; set; }
public DbSet<Marketplace> MarketPlaces  { get; set; }
```

So why do you want to have an extra repository layer?

One reason may be is to be able to fake the repository object because DbSet does not provide an interface that can be used for mocking or faking. For example let us create a generic repository class, from an interface type of IRepostory. The class Repository in this case will encapsulate DbSet for whatever model T.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T model);
    void Edit(T model);
    void Delete(T model);
    T Get(object id);
    IQueryable<T> List();
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    DatabaseContext context;
    DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public Repository(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T model)
    {
        dbSet.Add(model);
    }

    public void Edit(T model)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(model);
        context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete(T model)
    {
        if (context.Entry(model).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(model);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(model);
    }

    public T Get(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> List()
    {
        return dbSet;
    }
}
```

To instantiate a repository

```
var context = new DbContext();
var repo = new Repository<Marketplace>(context);
```

The *context* above is the UoW object. *Repo* is the instantiated repository object. To create a fake object what you will need is to derive from IRepository.